# This application requires iOS XX.x or later

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, ms-office

Ages ago, if I tried to install an app on an older version of iOS, it would alert you and allow you to install the last release of the app for the iOS you are on.

But when I tried again today at work to install Excel on a iOS 10 device I got, "This application requires iOS 11.x or later".

I know for a fact that Excel for iOS was available on iOS 10. Why is it not installing the older version applicable to iOS 10? Is there some quick and easy trick to make it do it? If not I'll have to tell management to get new iPad which they will not be happy about.

PS: I am familiar with the hacky way to force installation of older versions.

Comment: "Ages ago, if I tried to install an app on an older version of iOS, it would alert you and allow you to install the last release of the app for the iOS you are on." IIRC, it's up to the app developer whether or not this option appears. So yell at Microsoft.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing a bit more googling and a suggestion [here](https://forums.appleinsider.com/discussion/204044) I found a work around.

It appears the AppStore will not offer you the older version of the application if you have not downloaded it in the past (ie own it already). So the solution is,

1. Log in to the appstore from an up to date device (borrow one if you must).
2. Download the app you need.
3. Go back to your older device and locate the app in the appstore.
4. The icon to download the app should now be a cloud with the down arrow.
5. Press the cloud button and it will advise you that it will download the older version.

[image][image]

Comment: If you have no alternate iOS devices, I bet purchasing the app with iTunes 12.6 would also work!

Comment: @Wowfunhappy I tried that on v12.8 that I have installed and I could not get AppStore results. Is that the last version to have AppStore integration?

Comment: @Vic I believe the latest iTunes with AppStore integration is 12.6.4.3.

Comment: 12.6 is the last version with iTunes integration. *Because* of this, Apple has been releasing bugfix updates to 12.6 as a separate channel, and you can actually install the 12.6 branch alongside newer versions of iTunes.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy Thx. Good to know.